# How often do armored trucks spawn in GTAV Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Question pretty much says all. I am in an invite only session and I have the right level.

I'm only curious about how often they spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Based on personal experience, I think the spawning for armored trucks is a bit irregular. When you leave them be I think they spawn at some regular time interval (10+ minutes or so). But when you actually attack one (again, based on personal experience) they begin spawning right after you attack a truck. I'm not sure if this is a bug or how the game is designed, but this can make it extremely easy to farm money if you have a friend or two as you can keep constantly attacking trucks.

I have run into this twice now where trucks begin constantly spawning as long as you continue attacking them, otherwise they go right back to their regular time interval. If someone else knows more specific details I'd also be curious to know, but this is what I know.